# Excel function that returns a value if all columns meet a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a new column that returns either a '1' or a '0' if an individual has made it to the end of a sequence so I can use Vlookup to return their names and number of opens. They're considered to have finished the sequence if they are not paused, have not replied, and have not unsubscribed. They have to meet all three criteria i.e. D2 has to be "No", E2 & F2 have to be blank. If so, return 1, else return 0.

I'm having trouble with the COUNTIFS function (if that's even what I'm supposed to be using) and I'm not sure how to make it return a 1 or 0. I've attached a screenshot of the sheet below. Any help/ advice would be much appreciated!

[Here is a section of the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZPMz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a comparison with the concatenated columns: `=IF(D2&E2&F2="NO",1,0)` if the E2 or F2 are not blank it will be "NO2021-05-<etc.>"